# works in browser but not through CRON. Why?

Tags: php, jquery, cron

I have this jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(
function (){
$.get('update.php',function (){
});
},1000
);
</script>
```

It calls my update.php file every second which updates the database. This works without any problem when I manually run it on the browser but it doesn't work through CRON. What can I do to make it work through CRON jobs?

Comment: Java scripts are working based on browser so this is not practical to write in cronjobs

Comment: CRON jobs work by executing server-side scripts, as JS is a client-side technology it won't be executed

Comment: How do you call update.php in the Cron?

Comment: Cron jobs call php functions, so it really has nothing to do with jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your CRONTAB, you'll want to run update.php. Javascript/jQuery is run client-side. When setting up a CRON Job, you are running a command on the server, in this case, a PHP script. As such, only the PHP will run.

An example entry in CRONTAB:

```
*/1 * * * * php /path/to/update.php
```

This will run the command *php* every **minute**, passing it *update.php* as an argument.

More information about CRON format: http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

Comment: No, what is here is wrong :) .. CRON cannot run every second!! The minimum amount is 1 minute. Also the */1 is the exact same thing as *

Comment: You sir, are correct. Complete lapse of thought on my part. The minimum time frame for a CRON task is 1 minute, not second. */1 is the same thing as *, however I find it reduces confusion and can easily be changed to every two minutes, etc.